# Lua - Retrieve all second from last values from an inconsistent CSV file

Tags: csv, lua

I have a csv file (DailyEnergyCost.txt) that has many different variations of line entries, but it’s only the first and second from last values I want to retrieve. So I can plot them on a graph

```
2022-03-14 23:59:00, 23.51, 6.21, 0.264,
2022-03-15 23:59:00, 21.74, 5.74, 0.264,
2022-03-16 23:59:00, 18.87, 4.98, 0.264,
2022-03-23 09:00:37, 145.79, 38.49, 0.264,
2022-03-23 09:06:44, 3210.2370, 3210.5250, 0.29, 0.08, 0.264, 
2022-03-23 23:59:00, 3210.5250, 3224.2470, 13.72, 3.62, 0.264, 
2022-03-29 23:59:00, 1648508340, 1648594740, 3322.4630, 3343.3360, 20.87, 5.51, 0.264, 
2022-03-30 23:59:00, 1648594740, 1648681140, 3343.3360, 3365.2770, 21.94, 5.79, 0.264, 
2022-03-31 23:59:00, 1648681140, 1648767540, 3365.2770, 3395.7930, 30.52, 8.06, 0.264,
```

Now I’ve tried to do work out the logic of getting the last but one entry, using one line from the csv above in an array.. see below.. but that only works to a point.

```
local arr = {3210.5250, 3224.2470, 13.72, 3.62, 0.264}
for i,v in pairs(arr) do
    last = #arr - 1
end
print(last)
```

I also know there is the `lines` option too, to allow me to work my way through the file line by line ..

```
local file = io.open("www/DailyEnergyCost.txt")
local lines = file:lines()
for line in lines do
    print("\t" .. line)
end
```

But, please could someone share how you work line by line through the csv file that does not have consistent entries to extract the last but one entry?

Using the data source example as a guide above , the resulting Lua script should return the following. (First item and seconded from last).

```
2022-03-14 23:59:00, 6.21
2022-03-15 23:59:00, 5.74
2022-03-16 23:59:00, 4.98
2022-03-23 09:00:37, 38.49
2022-03-23 09:06:44, 0.08
2022-03-23 23:59:00, 3.62
2022-03-29 23:59:00, 5.51
2022-03-30 23:59:00, 5.79
2022-03-31 23:59:00, 8.06
```

Comment: `arr[#arr - 1]`

Comment: Thanks @shingo, that helps, although I’m not sure I understand how that works, are you able to explain ? (I’ve updated my earlier code too - local arr = {"2022-03-14 23:59:00", 3210.5250, 3224.2470, 13.72, 3.62, 0.264}
for i,v in pairs(arr) do
    last = arr[#arr - 1]

end
print(last)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the code I used in the end, huge thanks to @Mike V for his help on this..

```
local fh,err = io.open("www/DailyEnergyCost.txt")
    if err then print("file not found"); return; end

-- Open a file for write
local fho,err = io.open("/mnt/nas/DailyEnergyCostExtract.txt","wb")

local time, value

while true do
    line = fh:read()
        if line == nil then break end
        if line:gmatch("[^%c]+") then
            time = line:match("^(.-),")
            value = line:match(".+,%s+(.-),.-,") or ""
            -- print(time .. ", " .. value)
            fho:write(time .. ", " .. value)
            fho:write("\n")
        end
    end

fh:close()
fho:close()

-- Let’s just check the file.

local file = io.open("/mnt/nas/DailyEnergyCostExtract.txt")
local lines = file:lines()
for line in lines do
    print("\t" .. line)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

read the entire file and use the pattern to take values:

```
local fp = io.open("www/DailyEnergyCost.txt","rb")
local text = fp:read('*a')
print(text)
local time, value
for line in text:gmatch("[^%c]+") do
  time = line:match("^(.-),")
  value = line:match(".+,%s+(.-),.-,") or ""
  print(time .. ", " .. value)
end
```

explanation:

`"^(.-),"` :

`^` - from begin

`(.-),` - match all characters before first sign `,` (lazy quantifier)

`".+,%s+(.-),.-,"` :

`.+,` - all characters before 3rd sign `,` from ending, (greedy quantifier)

`%s+` - maximum spaces

`(.-),` - match our characters (minimum before `,`)

`.-,` -  it's not our characters - missing here.

Comment: Thanks @Mike V, however your suggestion just seems to return the last line of the file (-minus the date/time) ? I’ve updated my post with what I’d like to end up with if that helps?

Comment: ok, this is a different task, I corrected the answer

Comment: That’s great, thanks so much @Mike V, I’ve updated this post with my full answer now. I really struggle with pattern matching, so if you have time to explain each one a bit more that would be great, but not crucial if you don’t have time..

Comment: Thanks so much @ Mike V. for the pattern matching explanation - so, is the first `time` one, looking forward, and then the second  `value` one working backwards ?

Comment: all this is a bit conditional, in the first case it is possible without ^, by default forward viewing is used.
in the second case, you can consider the entire string, because there is .+, which will absorb all commas, until the following quantifiers are met.